# Исключить из кеширования

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

помогите, пожалуйста, исключить из кеширования следующий код (одна из функций в файле techmarket-woocommerce-template-functions.php):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'techmarket_header_wishlist' ) ) {
/**
 * Displays a link to wishlist page in header
 */
function techmarket_header_wishlist() {
    if( function_exists( 'techmarket_get_wishlist_url' ) ) {
        ?>
        <ul class="header-wishlist nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( techmarket_get_wishlist_url() ); ?>" class="nav-link"><i class="tm-wishlist-icon <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'techmarket_wishlist_icon', 'tm tm-favorites' ) ); ?>"></i><span id="top-cart-wishlist-count" class="tm-wcwl-ajax-count value"><?php echo yith_wcwl_count_products(); ?></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
}
```

}

Данный код отвечает за список избранных товаров - https://prnt.sc/qk21d2 (на скрине сердечко с цифрой 13 - количество избранных товаров). Проблема в том, что данное количество кешируется. Сайт сделан на вордпрессе, вукоммерс, плагин кеширования W3 Total Cache (бесплатная версия).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте в wp-config.php добавить

```
define('W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'my_string');
```

И заменить в шаблоне вызов этой функции:

```
<!-- mfunc techmarket_header_wishlist() --><!-- /mfunc -->
```

Comment: Ваше не работает. Взял решение отсюда - https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/w3-total-cache-fragment-caching-wordpress/. Поправил соответственно, define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'SOME_SECURE_STRING_YOU_CREATE' );, <!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
echo 'The time is '.date( 'H:i:s', time() );
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->.

Comment: Получилось что, значение пока не добавлю ничего не показывает - https://prnt.sc/qkf6zm

Comment: Может есть еще какие-то решения?

Answer (score 0):

Все получилось! Данное решение работает для плагина кеширования W3 Total Cache версия 0.12.0, WordPress 5.3.2

1. Шаг - добавил в function.php темы следующую строчку (при добавлении в файл wp-config.php - не работало) - `define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', 'SOME_SECURE_STRING_YOU_CREATE' );`
2. Вызов функции `<?php echo yith_wcwl_count_products(); ?>` оформил следующим образом - `<!-- mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> --> echo yith_wcwl_count_products(); <!-- /mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->`

Готовая функция полностью:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'techmarket_header_wishlist' ) ) {
    /**
     * Displays a link to wishlist page in header
     */
    function techmarket_header_wishlist() {
        if( function_exists( 'techmarket_get_wishlist_url' ) ) {
            ?>
            <ul class="header-wishlist nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( techmarket_get_wishlist_url() ); ?>" class="nav-link"><i class="tm-wishlist-icon <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'techmarket_wishlist_icon', 'tm tm-favorites' ) ); ?>"></i><span id="top-cart-wishlist-count" class="tm-wcwl-ajax-count value"><!-- mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> --> echo yith_wcwl_count_products(); <!-- /mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> --></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```